# Google App Engine (Python)- Strange behaviour of REMOTE_ADDR

Tags: python, google-app-engine, ip-address

In order to make the registration process on my website easy, I allow users to enter their email address which I will send a verification code to or alternatively they can solve a captcha.

The problem is that in order to prevent robots from registering accounts (with fake emails) I limit the number of registrations allowed per IP address and if this limit is exceeded I trigger a warning in the logs.

However ... what seems to be happening is that I am using os.environ['REMOTE_ADDR'] to check the remote address -- but it seems that I am triggering warnings on addresses that are owned by Google (66.249.65.XXX). It is possible that this is happening only after I change the version (but not confirmed). Does anyone know how/why this might be happening? Shouldn't the REMOTE_ADDR return the address of the client computer (and hopefully in all cases it would do this)?

I am curious if there is some behind the scenes re-directions going on, and if this is a normal event or if it only happens when a new version is installed (perhaps when a new version is installed the original server then proxies the user to the new server, therefore creating the illusion that the IP address is an internal IP?)

Comment: I just realized that this problem could also be caused by googles crawlers accessing the registration page that was previously accessed by clients (because for reasons that I don't want to get into, I pass registration info to the page using a GET instead of a POST) -- I don't know if this could then somehow trigger crawlers to go to the registration page based on feedback from the browsers or something -- I am quite curious to know what might be happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that I have figured out the reason for seeing so many warnings from google server IP addresses. It seems that immediately after a new user registers, the google crawlers are going to the same (registration) webpage (which I send information to as a GET instead of a POST for reasons which I will not get into). Of course, since many users are registering, but there are only a few crawler computers that are checking periodic updates to my website, I am triggering warning messages that a particular (google) IP is accessing a registration area repeatedly.

Comment: Making non-idempotent requests using GET is a terrible idea, unless you want malicious users signing other people up for accounts by embedding the URL in an image tag, for example.

Comment: I agree with you, I will look into changing it at some point in the future. However, in the meantime I have limits on the number of registrations for a given IP address, captchas that need to be solved before the information is written into the database (hence the use of the GET), and verification of uniqueness of the email address that is being registered.